# Redux Framework does not work on some files

Tags: wordpress, templates, frameworks, redux-framework

This code works in single.php but it does not work in content.php in the template-parts folder.

```
<?php if( $opt_name['content-meta-hide'] == '1' ){ ?>
    <div class="entry-meta">
    ...
    </div>
    <?php }; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );` in index.php on a template I only used a function in the content.php file in template-parts.

```
<?php if( $opt_name['content-meta-hide'] == '1' ){ ?>
<div class="entry-meta">
...
</div>
<?php }; ?>
```

It does not work when I do something in redux.